# Mysql LIMIT in subquery

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql statement but I receive LIMIT in subquery error

```
SELECT  id
FROM    articles
WHERE  section=1 AND id NOT IN 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    articles
        WHERE   is_top_story=1  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
        )
```

I want to select all id-s from table where section=1 and id-s not in my inner(second) statement

```
+--id--+section+-is_top_story-+--timestamp--+
|  54  |   1   |     1        |    130      |
|  70  |   2   |     0        |    129      |      
|  98  |   3   |     1        |    128      |
|  14  |   1   |     1        |    127      |
|  58  |   4   |     0        |    126      |
|  13  |   3   |     1        |    125      |
|  64  |   1   |     1        |    124      |
|  33  |   1   |     1        |    123      |
```

My sql should return 64 and 33(they are with section=1 and is_top_story=1), because 54 and 14 (are in inner statment)

If any can give me some code I will be very grateful

Thanks

Comment: Your example _excludes_ all articles from the inner select while your example seems to want them _included_. Could you clarify what you really want with a more complete example?

Comment: Some sample inputs and expected outputs would help as it is not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. The prose of your query reads *Give me all articles in section 1 where the article is not one of the two most recent top stories*. What is it that you actually want?

Comment: Btw, did you really name your column 'timestamp'?

Comment: Still a bit contradicting description, you say 33 should be returned since top_story=1, but what if top_story were 0? Your original query would return 33 anyway, but your example description says no.

Comment: thanks to all, sorry for my delay.I want this:Give me all id where `section = 1` but not some of those who meet this requirement `s_top_story = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.times
  FROM articles AS a
  LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT id
         FROM articles
        WHERE is_top_story =1
     ORDER BY times DESC LIMIT 2) AS ax
  USING (id)
WHERE section = 1 AND ax.id IS NULL;
```

Join is a usual workaround when you need limits in subqueries; need for excluding logic just adds these 'left join - joined.id IS NULL` parts to query. )

**UPDATE:** Got a bit confused by your example. The original query you've quoted was "take some articles with section = 1, then take out those that belong to the 2 most recent top_stories". But in your example the section should also be taken into account when selecting these stories-to-ignore-...

It's actually quite easy to update my query with that condition as well: just replace

```
WHERE is_top_story = 1
```

with

```
WHERE is_top_story = 1 AND section = 1
```

... but I think it might be even better solved at the client code. First, you send a simple query, without any joins whatsoever:

```
    SELECT id, is_top_story 
      FROM articles 
     WHERE section = 1
  ORDER BY times DESC;
```

Then you just walk through the fetched rowset, and just ignore two first elements with 'is_top_story' flag on, like that:

```
  ...
  $topStoriesToIgnore = 2;
  foreach ($rowset as $row) {
    if ($row->is_top_story && $topStoriesToIgnore-- > 0) {
      continue;  
    }
    // actual processing code goes here
  }
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't yet support `LIMIT` clause in subquery with `IN`, so this is a nice alternative.

Comment: Which does, btw? In MySQL 5.6 doc there's still "...doesn't yet support LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery..."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is that you want, the question is a little confuse. I don't understand why you use a subquery for the same table. Anyway LIMIT is the same of "TOP" for MSSQL, so LIMIT 2 should be only returns two records.

If this is not that you want please comment and I will edit my answer:

```
SELECT  id
FROM    articles
WHERE  section=1 AND is_top_story != 1
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```